# Embedding Video Cross Browser, Single format / Embed

Tags: html, video, cross-browser, video-streaming

I have a task ahead of me that I do not know the easiest way to address.  Currently I am building out an admin section in Symfony for a client and she would like to upload video.  She has the capability of conversion and will use the format I specify but I just do not know what the best on is for cross browser compatibility.  I think .mov seems pretty good but I do not know.  I would like simple embed code and to swap out the video src with js.  Any and all help appreciated as always.

Thank you in advance,

- J

Answer (score 0):

I think  currently the best option is H264 in a mp4-container with Flash based video player such as

http://flowplayer.org/

http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

If you want use HTML5 video I would suggest that you use some flash hybrid to get maximum browser support

Check this out:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-html5

Comment: I was looking for one file format solution since the user would be uploading this on there own.  I went with the Vimeo API as a nice solutino.